# limits.conf ограничения прав в группе

Tags: linux, limits

Доброго времени суток. Помогите понять логику работы группы pam Linux в limits.conf

Допустим, на memlock примере:
- есть пользователь user1 в группе @user1, пользователь user2 в группе @user2 все они состоят в группе @grouplimits.

Если я задаю группе @grouplimits ограничения:
@grouplimits soft memlock 524288
@grouplimits hard memlock 1048576

то пользователь user1 будет подчинятся лимиту, пока не войдёт user2, и разделит его лимит (это будет общий лимит на группу)? Или каждый из пользователь вошедший в группу будет иметь свой memlock = @grouplimits?

Спасибо.